# Werid colour for xubuntu title bar

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, xfce

[image]

The image above shows weird blue colour (formerly it was greyiish silver) for xubuntu title bar. It occurred without any reason one day I booted at the logon screen, as usual selected 'xubuntu-session' (I have also installed Gnome) but the title bar exhibited this blue phenomenon...everything else is normal!

I never tweaked default theme don't know why it happened, by default xubuntu theme is 'GreyBird'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml
and edit the line

```
<property name="theme" type="string" value="Default"/>
```

as follows:

```
<property name="theme" type="empty"/>
```

It happens to me after switching to Xfce session. I think it's is due to the fact that Xfce and Xubuntu sessions share the XFCE configuration directory, but are tuned to different defaults.